# Error: Invalid left hand sign assignment (II)

Tags: javascript

This conditional operator gives out a left hand assignment error, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
else if (schedule == undefined && season != "winter" && typeb = false) {
  console.log("It works");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One equal sign is an assignment. You need `typeb == false` or `typeb === false`

```
else if (schedule == undefined && season != "winter" && typeb == false) {
console.log("It works")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `=` (assignment operator) in a conditional - change it to `==` (comparison operator):

```
else if (schedule == undefined && season != "winter" && typeb == false) {...}
```

Or just use `!`:

```
else if (schedule == undefined && season != "winter" && !typeb) {...}
```